# Unable to generate meanjs application with yeoman

Tags: node.js, yeoman, meanjs, yeoman-generator

I am trying to follow the video tutorial of the [meanjs official website](http://meanjs.org/). I run the command `yo meanjs` to generate a meanjs project with yeoman generator. The command run until to produce the following error :

```
? Would you like to generate the chat example module? No
   create mean/package.json
   create mean/bower.json
   create mean/config/env/default.js
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd mean && npm install
npm WARN package.json xmen@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency istanbul@0.x.x included from grunt-mocha-istanbul will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:12: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object> &&' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'S *' against 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Primitive *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:414:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Primitive>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Boolean *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:424:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::True(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Function *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1514:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Function>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(handle)->Get(kCallbackIndex)
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1632:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(handle->Get(NanNew(key)).As<v8::Object>());
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:12: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object> &&' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'S *' against 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Primitive *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:414:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Primitive>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Boolean *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:424:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::True(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Function *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1514:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Function>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(handle)->Get(kCallbackIndex)
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1632:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(handle->Get(NanNew(key)).As<v8::Object>());
           ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.1.0
In file included from ../src/debug.cc:2:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
        

                             ^
1 warning and 10 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/debug/src/debug.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
module_path=/Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v46-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v46-darwin-x64/debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=/Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v46-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/node_modules/grunt-node-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.11
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/Working/MVPS/meanjstuto/mean/npm-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

I don't understand why i am getting this error and what to do ? I am new in MeanJS stack.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of your npm dependency is requiring `xmlbuilder`. This is a C package, so Node try to build the module but it throws.

That's not related to Yeoman or Meanjs. Maybe you're having an old or incompatible C compiler on your machine? Maybe xmlbuilder is broken? And maybe it's just incompatible with the version of node you're using...

I'd open an issue on the xmlbuilder repository.